# AJAX get multipart response

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipart

I'm working in a Phonegap project with Restfull Web Services and I need to obtain a PDF file by one of them. I can obtain response using Ajax but I don't know how to work with multipart response. If I read response as always and write a .pdf file with info between "%PDF-1.4" and "EOF", the result file it's a white PDF without information.

I had tried mpAjax project like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: urlWS,
   data: info,
   contentType:'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   type: 'post',
   success:{
     "application/json": function (response) {alert('info: ');},
     "application/pdf":callback_handleData
   },
   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert('AJAX ERROR');
   }
});
```

But no alert was thrown.

Response example:

```
--uuid:7c26de68-83e9-456a-a986-65dfa8e74d88

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Content-ID: <ROOT>



{"attachedContenId":"DOC","document":{"docName":"38522672H ","mimeType":"application/pdf","itemType":"FACTURASSIC","nodeId":"cm://FACTURASSIC/ITEMID:A1001001A13G04A93633J51684","size":1120990},"props":[{"atribute":"IDCLIENTE","value":"38522672H "},{"atribute":"NUMPOL","value":"000413SC "},{"atribute":"NUMFACTURASIC","value":"AB20130622824"},{"atribute":"FECHA","value":"2013-01-25"},{"atribute":"ENTIDAD","value":"2013 "},{"atribute":"APARTADO","value":"0056"},{"atribute":"FECHAFACT","value":"2013-01-16"},{"atribute":"TIPODOC","value":"FACTURA1CA_12031"}],"error":""}

--uuid:7c26de68-83e9-456a-a986-65dfa8e74d88

Content-Type: application/pdf

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Content-ID: <DOC>



%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<</Length 25
```

Any idea?

Comment: In a Rest Client pluggin I can read right if I make request with Content-type: application/json;charset=US-ASCII header. Any way, with ajax I obtain the same corrupted text